# HoloLens emulator on a virtual machine

Tags: hololens, hololens-emulator

I'm trying to develop for HoloLens but my laptop doesn't support the needed specs, so I was trying to figure out a virtualized solution (namely, using an Azure VM).

After unsuccessfully running the emulator on the Azure VM, I found that according to Microsoft (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh831531), "The Hyper-V role is not supported on a Microsoft Azure virtual machine", which kills that idea.

Does anyone know of an alternative virtual option for developing and running the HoloLens emulator, which doesn't rely on the host machine's (i.e. my laptop) specs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in the latest version of Unity which is Unity 5.5, there's a new feature called "Holographic Emulation" that will enable you to run on a simulated device directly in the editor.

As for the requirements, you need to have

1. Unity 5.5 installed in your machine
2. Windows 10 Anniversary Update (or later) installed

Here's the link to the [blog](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2016/09/29/introducing-holographic-emulation/) in case you want to check more details about the simulator

Answer (score 0):

Hololens emulator IS the Hyper-V virtual machine with Windows 10 and 3D graphic capabilities. The host machine should be able to run Hyper-V (CPU/BIOS limitation) and have a 3D adapter. More details are here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/using-the-hololens-emulator

Then you could install the emulator from

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/install-the-tools

Comment: The problem I had was trying to use a virtual machine as the host. It didn't support Hyper-V and I was looking for alternative virtual host options.

Answer (score -1):

Hololens emulator is not supported in VM due to CPU limitation, you can use holographic simulation in Unity instead.